# using %i to run on any for loop

Tags: objective-c

i have a general case of representing an int in a for loop.

i have some variables(it doesnt really matter) which are instance of menuItem(cocos2d) and the got numbers like this:

```
w1,w2,w3,w4...
```

and for the record each one of them is pointer to :

```
CCMenuItemImage *w1= .....
```

and they have this property: `w1.tag=1 w2.tag=2...`
now my basic issue is to run on a loop on this w's as follow :

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{

if ( w%i.tag <5 )
//do here
}
```

now i am trying to find a way to present the number coming after the w with my index!

its easy with nsstrings BUT  what if i need anything else that has a number after it ?

thanks lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Naming variables using sequential numbers is almost always a sign that you should be using an array instead.

```
@interface MyClass
{
    CCMenuItemImage *w[10]; // ten of them!
}
@end

@implementation MyClass

- (id) init
{
     self = [super init];
     if (!self) return nil;

     for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
     {
         w[i] = /* make a new one */;
         w[i].tag = i;
     }

     return self;
}
```

If you ever have homogeneous objects that differ only by their position in a sequence, then you need an array.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should be using an array of menus and images instead.

Comment: what kind of array? its not a string, its a CCMenuItem.... cant understand this answer

Comment: NSArrays can store objects of any type.

Comment: @Almo: NSArrays can't store objects of any type, `int`, `void *`, `struct`, etc are types that can't be stored in NSArrays (by default).

Comment: @dreamlax: Those are only "objects" in the plain-C sense of "thing which is known to occupy memory by the compiler".

Comment: Josh has it. I meant Objects, not just anything. Sorry if that was unclear. :)

Comment: @JoshCaswell: I know the difference, but when you say "objects of *any type*", I hardly see how that only means Objective-C objects. Objective-C and C are so close together that you have to be more descriptive about what you mean when you use words that describe different things from the two languages. For example, even **if** it was implied that only Objective-C objects can be stored in NSArrays, it is still incorrect, because I might have my own root object for example.

Comment: But ints are not objects. That is certain in Obj-C.

Comment: @Almo: ints are objects because the C standard says they are, and Objective-C is based off the C standard. The word "object" is ambiguous in Objective-C because it has its own definition in the C standard and its own conventional definition in Objective-C. The same with other terms.

Comment: Looks to me like ints are "primitives" in Obj-C.

Comment: @dreamlax: I don't think I've ever seen anyone use "object", in the context of ObjC, to mean _both_ "struct with an `isa` pointer which responds to messages" _and_ "any primitive/POD". Strictly speaking, yes, you're correct, but it seems like muddying water which is quite reasonably clear already.

Comment: I'm not saying they aren't "primitives", I'm saying "objects of any type" is an ambiguous phrase because *any type* would include not only "primitive" C types, but also Objective-C types that are fundamentally incompatible with NSArray, such as a custom root class, `@selector(...)`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

> now i am trying to find a way to present the number coming after the w
>   with my index!
>
> its easy with nsstrings BUT what if i need anything else that has a
>   number after it ?

Your w's aren't indexed -- they're separate variables that just happen to have similar names. If they're instance variables or properties, you could use key value coding to access them the way you're trying to. It'd be something like this:

```
NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"w%d.tag", i];
int tag = [[self valueForKey:key] intValue];
```

As great as KVC is, I don't think that's a particularly good use of it. If you want to access those objects by index, you should store them in a container that provides that. You could store the menu items in an array when you create them, or you could put them in the array in the code where you're accessing them. For example:

```
NSArray *items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:w1, w2, w3, w4, nil]; //add as many as you like
for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    if ([w objectAtIndex:i].tag < 5) {
    // whatever you like
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In ObjC if you wanted to print formatted strings there is a way to do it

NSString *formattedString = [NSString stringWithFormat@"%@ %i %@", @"Hello" , 1 , @"World"];

NSLog(@"formatted string : %@", formattedString); would print

"Hello1World" without quotes

FYI : formattedString is an autoreleased object, so do not release it again.

Comment: The question is not about formatting strings, but a way of manipulating variables with numbers in their name using a loop of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, and this is ***NOT RECOMMENDED***, you can actually get the address of instance variables using `object_getInstanceVariable` function.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"w%i", i];
    Ivar ivar = object_getInstanceVariable(self, [name UTF8String], NULL);
    CCMenuItemImage *w = (void *)((char *)self + ivar_getOffset(ivar));

    w.tag = i;
}
```

Remember, don't use this, it is purely an educational answer.